# Using VBA for attachments

Tags: vba, attachment

I'm trying to use VBA to attach a file to an existing table but I keep running into a Runtime 3709 error as documented on the line below.  I have a table with a few thousand files in it.  What I would like to do is give the user the ability to select the file to be attached and when it's saved, the name will show up on the form.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Dim rsParent As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsAttachment As DAO.Recordset2
Dim strFileName As String
Dim SQL As String
Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
Dim varFile As Variant

Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fDialog
    .Title = "Choose the document to add to the form..."
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\"

    If .Show = True Then
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            GoTo SubExit
        End If ''

        For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
            strFileName = varFile
        Next
    Else
        GoTo SubExit
    End If
End With 

SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblTable WHERE RecordID = " & Me.tbxRecordID

'Instantiate the parent recordset
Set rsParent = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset) ''

If rsParent.recordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There was a problem locating the selected record", vbCritical + 
vbOKOnly, "Error"
    GoTo SubExit
Else
    ' Put recordset in edit mode
    rsParent.Edit
    'Set the child recordset
   Set rsAttachment = rsParent.Fields("Document").Value '**Runtime 3709 - 
Search key not found**
   'Add new attachment
   rsAttachment.AddNew
   rsAttachment.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile strFileName
   rsAttachment.Update

   rsParent.Update
   frmAttachments.Requery
   End If

SubExit:
On Error Resume Next
   If Not rsParent Is Nothing Then
        rsParent.Close
        Set rsParent = Nothing
    End If
    Exit Sub '

SubError:
    MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & " = " & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
        "An error occurred"
    GoTo SubExit '
End Sub
```

Comment: You are trying to assign a string value to a Recordset2 object...this is not allowed.

Comment: Ok. I changed the line to: Set rsAttachment = rsParent!Document.Value and still get the same error.  How am I assigning it a string if the value is a set of the parent set?  I'm relatively new to this. Thanks.

Comment: I would need to understand your database structure to better help you, but Im pretty sure you will need something like Set rsAttachment = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE foreigh_key = " & rsParent.Fields("Document").Value, dbOpenDynaset) or something similar.

Comment: Here is something else I just noticed.  The table I'm trying to save the attachment to was not designated as a DAO.Database.  When I try to do that, I get an error when I go to save it - the same error I'm getting above.  Is there a way to convert to a DAO?  Is this even needed or am I missing the boat?  Any help is appreciated. Thanks,